# slideshow in DRY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to optimize jquery script to multiple elements (many slideshow on single page).
I can add few function but this is not DRY (Dont repeat yourself).

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything.
   </div>
</div>



$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

[demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SimpleSlideshow/)

Answer (score 1):

use `class="slideshow"` Instead `id="slideshow"` (in the CSS Also):

```
$(".slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
    $('.slideshow').each(function() {
        $(this).children('div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo(this);
    });

},  3000);
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bb9rnLkq/2/**